# How does Cloud Run scaling down to zero affect long-computation jobs or external API requests?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm new to using Cloud Run and the idea of scaling down to zero is very appealing to me, but I have question about a few scenarios about its usage:

1. If I have a Cloud Run instance querying an external API endpoint, would the instance winds down while waiting for the response if no additional requests come in (i.e. I set the query time out to 60min, and no requests are received in that 60 min)?
2. If the Cloud Run instance is running computation that lasts for longer than 24 hour, or perhaps even days, without receiving requests, could it be trusted to carry out the computation until it's done without being randomly shutdown or restarted for servicing or other purposes (I ask this because Cloud Run is primarily intended as for stateless applications, but I have infrequent computation jobs that may take a long time that may be considered "stateful" in short-term context).
3. Does CPU utilization impact auto-scaling (e.g. if I have a computationally intensive job not configured for distributed computing running on one instance, would this trigger Cloud Run to spawn additional instances?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you deep dive in the documentation, I'm quite sure that you can find your answers. So, here a summary

1. ([Interesting read](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/lifecycle-container-cloud-run)).The Cloud Run instances are shut down only when they aren't in used (usually 15 minutes (can change at any time, no commitment, only observations) without request handling). In your case, if you are in a request handling context, no worries, your instance won't be killed, it is in use! *Note: don't send an HTTP response before the end of the processing. Background process/jobs aren't considered in a request context. The context is considered from the receipt of the request to the response (OK or KO) back. Partial response/streaming is accepted.*
2. Cloud run instance can, potentially, live more than 24h, but nothing is guaranteed. And, because the request handling is limited to 1h, you can't run process longer that that. I recommend you to have a look to [GKE autopilot](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/introducing-gke-autopilot) or to [run a container on a Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers) and stop the VM at the end of the processing to save resources and money (or a hack to run your container on [AI PLatform custom training](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs); even if you train nothing, you run a custom container on a serverless platform!). *If you can, I recommend you to design your workload to be split in several small and parallelizable jobs*
3. Yes, [it's described here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-instance-autoscaling). But keep in mind that only 1 request is processed on one instance. If you send a request that trigger an intensive compute job, the request will be only processed on the same instance (that can have several CPUs if your workload is compliant with that). And if another request comes in during the intensive processing, another Cloud Run instance will be spawn to handle it; only the new request.

Comment: I think the third point also depends on your concurrency setting and how much of a computationally intensive job you have, by default the concurrency setting is 80 (which you can change to 1 if you want) so if an existing instance has enough resources it can utilise existing instance for that requests depending on these factors.